# if I am NOT paying for life Insurance, is it permissable?

Tags: hadith, riba, insurance

Assalamualaikum. Most of us are familiar insurance is considered haram because of the presence of riba/interest. I've started working for US government and government employees are automatically given life insurance upon their hiring. There is nothing I paid or anything I need to pay into; it is free and government covers all the costs and I cannot opt out.

In this very specific scenario, would this be considered riba or not permissible?

Jazak'allah khairan